# Entity Framework "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asynchronous, entity-framework-6

I hope I can summarize this issue well enough.
Let's start with the setup.

### Setup

We have an ASP.NET Core Application and use Entity Framework (without Core).
We use a general AuthorizeFilter for all controllers:

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
        options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
})
```

And we have additional authorize policies applied to some controllers. e.g.:

```
[ApiController]
[Authorize("UserHasActivatedFeature")]
[Authorize("IsPremiumUser")]
public class PremiumFeatureController : ControllerBase
```

These policies are handled both with a single IAuthorizationHandler implementation. Looking like this:

```
public class UserAuthorizationHandler : IAuthorizationHandler
{
    private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;
    public UserAuthorizationHandler(IUserRepository userRepository)
    {
        _userRepository = userRepository;
    }
    public Task HandleAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context)
    {
        var pendingRequirements = context.PendingRequirements.ToList();

        foreach (var requirement in pendingRequirements)
        {
            switch (requirement)
            {
                case PremiumRequirement:
                    if (_userRepository.IsPremium(userId))
                    {
                        context.Succeed(requirement);
                    }

                    break;
                case FeatureActivatedRequirement:
                    if (_userRepository.IsFeatureActivated(userId))
                    {
                        context.Succeed(requirement);
                    }

                    break;
            }
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

and the UserRepository looks like this:

```
public class UserRepository : IRepository<User>, IUserRepository
{
    private DbSet<User> DbSet { get; private set; }
    public UserRepository(UnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        DbSet = unitOfWork.DbContext.Set<User>();
    }
    public bool IsPremium(int userId)
    {
        return DbSet.AsNoTracking().Any(user => user.Id == userId && user.IsPremium);
    }
    public bool IsFeatureActivated(int userId)
    {
        return DbSet.AsNoTracking().Any(user => user.Id == userId && user.IsFeatureActivated);
    }
}
```

### Problem

On our test environment, where about 20 people are testing our application. There are sometimes exceptions thrown from UserAuthorizationHandler saying: "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first". When this exception is thrown it is thrown twice once from IsPremium and once from IsFeatureActivated.

### Stacktrace (only 1 of the 2)

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ValidateConnectionForExecute(SqlCommand command)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ValidateCommand(String method, Boolean async)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute[TResultType](ObjectContext context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass41_0.<GetResults>b__0()
at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__31_0()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at awesomeCompany.Repositories.UserRepository.IsPremium(Int32 userId)
at awesomeCompany.API.Handlers.UserAuthorizationHandler.HandleAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context)
Inner Exception:
System.InvalidOperationException: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ValidateConnectionForExecute(SqlCommand command)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ValidateCommand(String method, Boolean async)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
```

### What did I try?

As I said above this exception only appears from time to time (like 2 or 3 times a day) so I tried to isolate the issue locally and created unit tests to test the repository with multiple parallel calls at once, but I could not reproduce the issue. Calling the methods 100 times at the same time seams to be completely fine.

I read many similar questions here on stackoverflow. Many seam to have this issue when using a query inside another query or inside a IEnumerable loop, but since I am only using an Any() method on the database entities inside a normal foreach-loop iterating through a list that is completely unrelated from the userRepository I am not sure if any of the solutions apply here.

Also applying the Setting MultipleActiveResultSets=true to the connection string seams not to be a good solution and I would only consider it as a last option.

Comment: Why is this line not recursive `return DbSet.AsNoTracking().Any(user => user.Id == userId && user.IsPremium);`

Comment: IAuthorizationHandler is probably injected as a singleton and your context is either scoped or transient. Depending on your container, you'll have to get the object instance via a scope factory (ie: IServiceScopeFactory).

Comment: @GHDevOps yes the IAuthorizationHandler is injected as a singleton. The _userRepository is injected as Transient. The context is just a parameter of the HandleAsync method so there is no injection of the context needed. Or do you mean I need to inject the repository differently?

Comment: @Charlieface sorry I don't understand your question. What are you suggesting? Any() is looping through the entities, but I am not calling another query or something else inside of it. But maybe I am just blind to something obvious here...

Comment: Well it's running inside the `IsPremium` property getter, and it's calling `user.IsPremium` so it seems to be recursive

Comment: Your repository is injected correctly. You can't have a child transient object inside a singleton parent. If you're using the IServiceCollection for MVC then you'll have to get your repository reference via the IServiceScopeFactory. I'm not sure how you're getting your reference to _userRepository??

Comment: @Charlieface ah I see, but the IsPremium method is part of the repository and the user variable is not an instance of the repository so these two IsPremium's are completely different. I could have made my example cleared by naming it differently. In the context of user.IsPremium it is just supposed to be a boolean property of the user entity.

Comment: Your HttpContext should have a list of items and inside that list you should see a reference to IServiceScope (HttpContext.Items[typeof(IServiceScope)] as IServiceScope;). Then use that instance to get your factory (serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(IServiceScopeFactory)))

Comment: @GHDevOps I updated my example of the UserAuthorizationHandler class. There you can see that I am just injecting the repository as I normally would with any other services or controllers.

Comment: @René using a singleton *is* the bug. A DbContext is neither thread-safe nor meant to be long lived. It's a Unit-of-Work that should be disposed when the work is done. By making `IAuthorizationHandler` you're also keeping a `DbContext` instance as a singleton and end up using it concurrently from multiple requests

Comment: Inject the IServiceScopeFactory instead and use that to get a new instance of your repository: using (var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope()) { var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IUserRepository>(); }

Comment: @René to fix the problem either change the auth handler to scoped or inject `IServiceProvider` instead of `IUserRepository` and create a new repository instance inside a scope in `HandleAsync`. This is explained in [Consuming a scoped service in a background task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#consuming-a-scoped-service-in-a-background-task)

Comment: Thanks to you two for these suggestions. I will code it up tomorrow and update my post here when I am done :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is using a singleton in the first place. A DbContext is neither thread-safe nor meant to be long lived. It's a Unit-of-Work that caches any pending changes and either commits them all atomically when `SaveChanges` is called, or discards them when disposed. This means a DbContext should always be disposed once the unit of work is done.

Nothing is gained by using a singleton DbContext either. It's not a connection, so no time is saved by keeping it around for long. A DbContext opens and closes connections itself when it has to read data or persist changes. It doesn't keep them alive.

By making `IAuthorizationHandler` you're also keeping a `DbContext` instance as a singleton and end up using it concurrently from multiple requests. You may not get any exceptions until two requests try to read from the DbContext instance simultaneously.

**Solution**

*Make UserAuthorizationHandler scoped*

To fix this problem, the easiest solution seems to be to make `UserAuthorizationHandler` a scoped instance. The code posted here doesn't seem to use any other singleton services so it doesn't need to be a singleton itself.

*Use scopes explicitly*

If it has to remain a singleton, the DbContext and by extension, the UserRepository will have to be created inside a scope as needed. In this case, inside `HandleAsync`. To do that you need to inject `IServiceProvider` instead of `IUserRepository`. This is explained in [Consuming a scoped service in a background task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#consuming-a-scoped-service-in-a-background-task) :

```
public class UserAuthorizationHandler : IAuthorizationHandler
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _services;
    public UserAuthorizationHandler(IServiceProvider services)
    {
        _services = services;
    }
    public Task HandleAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context)
    {
        using (var scope = Services.CreateScope())
        {
            using(var userRepository=scope.GetRequiredService<IUserRepository>())
            {
                var pendingRequirements = context.PendingRequirements.ToList();
                ...
            }
        }
    }
```

BTW *don't* use blocking IO/database calls in an async method. This blocks a thread that could be used to serve other requests *and* increasing CPU usage due to spinwaits. A *lot* of the performance gains in ASP.NET Core come from avoiding unnecessary blocks

This means that either `IsPremium` and `IsFeatureActivated` should become asynchronous, or, if the synchronous methods are really needed, that async versions should be added. In this particular case both methods are used, so a good idea would be to use a *single* query to return both values :

```
public async Task<(bool isPremium,isFeatureActivated)> FeaturesForAsync(int userId)
{
    var results=await _context.Users
                        .Where(u=>u.Id==userId)
                        .Select(u=>new {u.IsPremium,u.IsFeatureActivated})
                        .SingleOrDefaultAsync();

    if (results==null) return default;
    return (results.IsPremium,results.IsFeatureActivated);
}
```

Or, using records instead of tuples :

```
record UserFeatures(bool IsPremium,bool IsFeatureActivated);

public async Task<(bool isPremium,isFeatureActivated)> FeaturesForAsync(int userId)
{
    var results=await _context.Users
                        .Where(u=>u.Id==userId)
                        .Select(u=>new UserFeatures( 
                                         u.IsPremium,
                                         u.IsFeatureActivated))
                        .SingleOrDefaultAsync();

    return results ?? new UserFeatures(false,false);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer. I think I will go with the first solution and make the handler a scoped instance, because I don't a reason why it needs to be singleton either. Though I am wondering are there other advantages with the second solution using a ServiceProvider? Better performance maybe?
For the second part of your answer I think combining the two methods isn't a good idea. In this case maybe when both policies are used maybe, but the policies are also used each for there own in other scenarios. But I will definitely change the Any() calls to AnyAsync() for better performance.

Comment: @René executing N queries to get N attributes from a *single* row is a bad idea. You aren't isolating or abstracting anything. The overhead of those N queries is far greater than changing from blocking to non-blocking queries.

Comment: the real scenario is more complex than the code example I show here. I tested the performance of your suggestion to reduce the two queries into one, but the result was just as fast as the code was before. Also this made the code much more complex and less flexible. So I think I will stay with 2 separate queries. If we need this to be more scalable in the future, I will reconsider this solution.